# Check the word whether have zero and prepand in jquery/ javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

The case here is

I have numbers from 1 - 999 and I need to prepand the zero if there is not enough for 3 digit

eg.

```
1 => 001
9=>009
11=> 011
111 =>111
```

Is there any way to do this kind of task? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function get3DigitStr(num) {
  if (num > 99) return num + "";
  var s = "00" + num;
  return s.substr(-3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `pad(number,length)` function takes a number and the amount of padding to add to it.  It then loops n times adding a 0 each time until the length is satisfied.

```
   function pad(number, length) {
      var str = '' + number;
      while (str.length < length) {
         str = '0' + str;
      }
      return str;
   }

    var results = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 999; i++){
       results[i] = pad(i,3); 
    }

    console.log(results);
            /* Outputs ["001","002","003","004", "005", "006","007","011","012","013","014","015","111","222", "333"]*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var value
while ((value+"").length < 3)
    value = "0" + value;
document.write(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
function add(value) {
    return value.length < 3 ? add("0"+value) : value
}
```

Here's some examples:

```
var newvalue = add("1"); //newvalue = "001"
var newvalue = add("21"); //newvalue = "021"
var newvalue = add("999"); //newvalue = "999"
```

You can test it out here: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9PmFS/2/)